# Extract a specified data object that resides inside a PDF form field to an external file

Tags: json, pdf, text, import, export

I am looking for a script to extract a data object nested inside a data object to a new data object. Aside from being able to easily clone the object by creating a new one, while I can also extract one of several objects nested inside an object that includes all its related properties and values, the name associated with the property and values is missing. Hence, I require a script to create a new object containing any one of several names including its related properties and values extracted from the existing object provided below.

```js
{"J Doe Company":{"lastUpdate":"01/05/2023","website":"jdoecompany.com","userID":"jdoe1985@gmail.com","password":"igfndhsi1985","primaryCC":"Discover","secondaryCC":"Capital One","primaryBank":"Chase","secondaryBank":"","sq1":"Year Graduated HS","sa1":"1985","sq2":"","sa2":"","notes1":"Sample password record","notes2":""},"Bob The Builder":{"lastUpdate":"01/05/2023","website":"bobthebuilder.com","userID":"bobthebuilder@gmail.com","password":"bbob1985","primaryCC":"Amazon Visa","secondaryCC":"Mastercard","primaryBank":"Wells Fargo","secondaryBank":"","sq1":"First Girlfriend's Name","sa1":"Kaye","sq2":"","sa2":"","notes1":"Sample password record","notes2":""},"SpongeBob Square Pants":{"lastUpdate":"01/07/2023","website":"spongebobsquarepants.com","userID":"spongebob@gmail.com","password":"spongebob1999","primaryCC":"None/Not Applicable","secondaryCC":"","primaryBank":"None/Not Applicable","secondaryBank":"","sq1":"Year show debuted on TV","sa1":"1999","sq2":"","sa2":"","notes1":"Animated TV show for kids","notes2":""}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run `cpdf -output-json in.pdf -o put.json` and process the result. The format is described in the cpdf manual.

Answer (score 0):

Upon further trial and error after learning more about how to create and edit an object literal, the script required to add an object along with its key-value properties is as follows:

```
dsFld =getField("dataSrc");// dataSRC is a hidden field containing a JS object converted to a JSON string
oVendors = JSON.parse(dsFld.value); // oVendors is a JS object
oVendors[event.value]=oVendorsPropValues;//oVendorsPropValues = {key-value pairs}
dsFld.value = JSON.stringify(oVendors);// convert the JS obj back to a JSON string
```